# javascript : parse float with string prefix in both start and end

Tags: javascript, regex

how to convert this string to float?
i want result 900.50

case-1: `var convertThis = 'any string here 900,50 also any string here';`

case-2: `var convertThis = 'any string here 900.50 also any string here';`

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var myFloat = +(convertThis.match(/\d+[,\.]?\d+/)[0].replace(",","."))`

Comment: then use the parseFloat(myFloat) ?

Comment: Nope, no need for that, the `+` before the paranthesis already "casts" the string to a number

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
var num = parseFloat(convertThis.replace(/[^\d\.,]/g,'').replace(/,/,'.'));
```

But be aware that this would break as soon as you have more than one number or dot in your text. If you want something reliable, you need to be more precise about what the string can be.

Supposing you'd want to extract all numbers from a more complex strings, you could do

```
var numbers = convertThis.split(/\s/).map(function(s){
    return parseFloat(s.replace(',','.'))
 }).filter(function(v) { return v });
```

Here, you'd get `[900.5]`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
var text = 'any string here 900,50 also any string here';
var matched = text.match(/\d+[,.]\d+/)[0].replace(',', '.');
var num = parseFloat(matched, 10);
console.log(matched);
console.log(num);
```

prints:

```
900.50
900.5
```